# What does forwardRef by a component in React dev tools mean and how can I use it?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

When I inspect component structure in React dev tools, I can see that there is a `forwardRef` mark. I am perplexed because there is no sign of it being used in the source code. How is it that it is there and how can I use it?

[image]

Comment: Probably you are using a library that internally uses `forwardRef` to give you access to the elements inside wrappers made by library.

Provide some code to understand better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `forwardRef` calls aren't in your own code, they are in the packages that you are using.

`styled.button` appears to be from `styled-components`.  This package uses `forwardRef` to forward any `ref` that you set on your styled button component to the underlying `button` component.  You can see it in their source code [right here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/404190e26062133a7b916d73c1d52312db20bc92/packages/styled-components/src/models/StyledComponent.js#L252):

```
WrappedStyledComponent = ((React.forwardRef(forwardRef): any): IStyledComponent);
```

Usage of `forwardRef` began with styled-components v4 -- see step #2 on [this migration guide](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#what-do-i-need-to-do-to-migrate-to-v4):

> Make sure your application is using react >= 16.3; internally we are using the new `React.forwardRef` API and new context APIs if you wish to try and polyfill for older React version support

It is also explained on this [Tips and Tricks page](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/72a6f642c3dedbcee91a2b5d76f96b93f345b86f/packages/styled-components/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes):

> **Refs to DOM nodes**
>
> styled-components makes use of the new React 16.3 API `forwardRef`. Thus, set refs like you would on any other component and they will automatically resolve to the underlying DOM element or wrapped component class instance.