# What does "ForwadRef" mean in React developer tools?

Tags: reactjs, react-developer-tools

Apparently, all documentation of React developer tools has moved to the main React page, where I cannot find any documentation about React developer tools.

I wonder why my functional component appears with a "ForwardRef" icon attached:

[image]

A hint to any documentation is also appreciated. All I find is this blog entry https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `forwardRef` is used to pass an object or a function reference down to its children. For more information, see the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: I do not use ForwardRef, I have a plain function component with hooks. Why does React DevTools show ForwardRef?

Comment: In that case might your question be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116058/what-does-forwardref-by-a-component-in-react-dev-tools-mean-and-how-can-i-use-it)